# System of linear homogeneous differential equations with complex eigenvalue

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I need to solve the system of the DE:
$$
\begin{cases} \frac{dx}{dt} = 2x-4y,  \\ \frac{dy}{dt} =x+2y+z,\\ \frac{dz}{dt} = 3y+2z, \end{cases}
$$
First, I rewtite the coefficents in the matrix form:
$$A = \begin{bmatrix}
2 & -4 & 0\\
1 & 2 & 1\\
0 & 3 & 2
\end{bmatrix}$$
Then, I find $$det(A-\lambda I) = \begin{vmatrix}
2 - \lambda  & -4 & 0\\
1 & 2 - \lambda & 1\\
0 & 3 & 2 - \lambda
\end{vmatrix}
=-(\lambda-2)(\lambda-(2-i))(\lambda-(2+i))
$$
For $\lambda =2$ the approach is not very difficult - I will solve the system $Ev =0$ where $E=A-\lambda I$ and $v = \begin{bmatrix} x\\ y\\ z \end{bmatrix}$.
But this approach is much for difficult more complex $\lambda$.

Comment: What does the general solution look like for a $2\times2$ coefficient matrix with complex eigenvalues? Extrapolate from that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we stay within real matrices, we cannot diagonalize the coefficient matrix, but we can block-diagonalize it.For $\lambda=2$, an eigenvector is $$\begin{bmatrix}-1\\0\\1\end{bmatrix}$$ For $\lambda=2+i$, an eigenvector is $$\begin{bmatrix}-4\\i\\3\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}-4\\0\\3\end{bmatrix}+\begin{bmatrix}0\\1\\0\end{bmatrix}i$$
Let $$P=\begin{bmatrix}-1&-4&0\\0&0&-1\\1&3&0\\\end{bmatrix}$$ Let $$\check D=\begin{bmatrix}2&0&0\\0&2&-1\\0&1&2\end{bmatrix}$$ Then $P^{-1}AP=\check D$ Let $$\begin{bmatrix}x\\y\\z\end{bmatrix}=P\begin{bmatrix}u\\v\\w\end{bmatrix}$$ Then $$\begin{bmatrix}du/dt\\dv/dt\\dw/dt\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}2&0&0\\0&2&-1\\0&1&2\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}u\\v\\w\end{bmatrix}$$ $$u=ae^{2t},v=e^{2t}(b \cos t+c \sin t),w=e^{2t}(-c \cos t+b \sin t)$$. You can take it from here.

Comment: Could you please comment oh how you got eigenvector for $\lambda = 2+i$. You just took the second column of $A-\lambda I $ matrix?

Comment: @student: Work out A-(2+i)I. This matrix has determinant 0, so a vector in the solution space, i.e. an eigenvector, can be obtained by going along a row of A-(2+i)I and taking co-factors..